# Is there any replacement for push notification in Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

For some reasons I can not use push notification but I had to have such this ability in my application that send a notification from back-end (`Oracle Apex`) to special available user's application. One possible way I think is using `SMS` but I don't know is there any better way?

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you can't send push notification from Oracle Apex?

Comment: Apple and google are not allowing to access pus notification service because of Sanctions of Iran.

Comment: Well I thought of suggesting you OneSignal but then again you need the Apple's or Google's push notification services to use it

Comment: I think even if I use sms there should be a something may call `memory resident` that permanently check sms inbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can push notifications to users when certain actions are triggered with Toast,
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toast/ToastController/

The API docs give some background on them, I'd suggest starting from there

Comment: any Idea about using phonertc or any thing like IP or third parties?

Comment: That I am not too certain about, sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

I think the best alternative to push notifications is local notifications and it is much more simpler to add to any application.

As Josh Morony says:
There are two main types of notifications when it comes to mobile applications: local notifications and push notifications. It can be a little confusing to understand the difference, but essentially:
Local notifications can only be triggered by events on the user’s device
Push notifications can be triggered by events outside of the user’s device

this is docs:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/local-notifications/

this is tutorial about how to use it with more explanation.
https://www.joshmorony.com/getting-familiar-with-local-notifications-in-ionic-2/